# Вывести самый длинный массив через reduce?

Tags: javascript, html

Значение самого большого массива я нахожу , да и в консоле оно светится ,а как именно в out вывести ,не понимаю

```
let a = [[1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4 ], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]];
    
const f1 = () => {
    let res = a.reduce((accum, item, index) => {

        if (item.length > accum) {
            accum = item.length;
            return accum;
        }
        else {
            return accum;
        }



    }, 0);
    document.querySelector('.out').innerHTML = res;
}
```

Comment: Покажите ваш html тег, в который вы пытаетесь добавить значение

Comment: Массив a14, а в функции просто 'a'.  И функцию то надо вызвать. И не надо функцию называть function

Comment: @PavelNazarian да там не в этом проблема, а в том, что не получается в HTML тег записать результат

Comment: @SwaD конкретно тут я вижу, что функция нигде не вызывается, как минимум

Comment: мне нужно выести этот массив в out ,значение самого длинного эта функция и так выводит

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a14 = [[1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4 ], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]];
    
const maxArrayLength = () => {
    let res = a14.reduce((accum, item, index) => {

        if (item.length > accum) {
            accum = item.length;
            return accum;
        }
        else {
            return accum;
        }



    }, 0);
    document.querySelector('.out').innerHTML = res;
}

maxArrayLength()
```

```html
<div class="out"></div>
```